# "break" vs "raise StopIteration" in a Ruby Enumerator

Tags: ruby, enumerator

If I use Ruby Enumerators to implement a generator and a filter:

```
generator = Enumerator.new do |y|
  x = 0
  loop do
    y << x
    x += 1
    break if x > CUTOFF
  end
end.lazy

filter = Enumerator.new do |y|
  loop do
    i = generator.next
    y << i if i.even?
  end
end
```

does it make any difference whether I break out of the generator's loop using

```
break if x > CUTOFF
```

vs

```
raise StopIteration if x > CUTOFF
```

?

Both seem to work. I imagine `break` would be more performant, but is `raise` more idiomatic here?

Comment: Because you're working with `lazy` I'd personally opt for `raise StopIteration`.

Comment: This seems like a very pythonic way of using ruby.  Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, there may be a better way to achieve it

Comment: @Zack The example isn't very representative of my real use-case -- just an overly simple example to demonstrate the issue I'm running into. The real generator makes a sequence of api calls, fetching records in batches, yielding each record one at time until it needs to fetch another batch. That's all wrapped in another Enumerator that filters out the records that are relevant to the calling code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby it's [considered a bad practice](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-exceptional-flows) to use `raise/fail` for control flow as they are really slow.

So to answer your question `raise StopIteration if x > CUTOFF` isn't an idiomatic way of breaking from the loop

Comment: Tisk*Tisk since this is exactly how [`Enumerator#next`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) handles exiting a loop. (as well as `#peek` and `#next_values`. Honestly I would always use `raise StopIteration` for a `Kernel#loop` or an `Enumerator` since clearly the ruby team not only supports this concept but relies on it personally

Comment: @engineersmnky unfortunately old parts of both rails and ruby consist of code that aren't considered idiomatic today. Mike Perham _(creator of sidekiq)_ wrote [a great post](http://www.mikeperham.com/2010/11/22/the-ruby-stdlib-is-a-ghetto/) about it

Comment: using most "keywords" is not idiomatic generally speaking (break being a keyword). Chances are there is a better implementation all together `LazyEnumerator` would be my suggestion. I think if the core team wanted to fix the use of `StopIteration` it woudl be simple given its limited scope

Comment: Interesting never thought that using keywords isn't idiomatic. It's a basic language  syntax, see nothing wrong with using it. Although I agree that there are better implementations altogether

Comment: Given the back and forth on this, I'm inclined to use a simple `break` in simple cases like this, and resort to raising `StopIteration` when necessitated by a nested method call within the loop or when doing so would significantly improve the clarity of code.