# How do I total the random numbers generated in ruby

Tags: ruby, random

I have the code, that will generate random numbers, unless the generated random number is 0. When the result is 0, the loop breaks.

So when the loop breaks, I want a code, that keeps adding the random numbers that kept generated and display it at the last. Can I do that in ruby?

```
def batting
    loop do
    runs = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
    myruns = runs.shuffle.first
    Newscore = 
    puts "Press W to hit a shot"
    user_input = gets.chomp
    while user_input.include? "W"
        puts myruns
        until myruns == 0
            break
            Score = Score + myruns
            break
```

This is throwing `Dynamic Constant assignment` error at `Score = Score + myruns` which I basically think, its wrong, since the `myruns` keep changing at every generated event?

So, I would want to create a new variable, that would store the total of all the random numbers generated until the generated random number is 0.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are looking for something like this ?

```
def batting
  runs = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
  final_score = 0
  puts "Press W to hit a shot"
  user_input = gets.chomp     

  while user_input.include? "W"
    myruns = runs.sample

    if myruns != 0
      final_score += myruns
    else
      break
    end

    puts "myruns=#{myruns}","final_score=#{final_score}"
    puts "Press W to hit a shot"
    user_input = gets.chomp
  end
  puts "myruns=#{myruns}","final_score=#{final_score}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this, It actually prints multiple random numbers, and not one at a time and why is `myruns = runs.sample` created twice? once in the `while` loop and the next time in `until'?

Comment: The code that I wrote above, prints one random number each time you press `W`. I wanted to create a variable that would add up the random numbers, generated each time, until myruns = 0, post that `break` and add  the sum to the final score, so that, each time, this `def` is called, it doesn't disturb the final score. In order to do that, I would need a variable that stores the sum and not an array.

Comment: Can you please be more clearly what you need to get just in words?

Comment: 1. Generating `Random number` each time `W` is pressed.


2. If `Random number` is 0, `break` and `total` the Random number generated till now, and assign it to a variable.

Comment: Thats progress! Wow! if `myruns !=0` Keep adding the numbers is the  key to the logic here. Amazing, till now, I had been waiting to get it `0` to add the generated numbers as a whole. This is much better solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def batting
  loop.with_object([]) do |_,obj|
    x = rand 7
    x == 0 ? raise(StopIteration) : obj << x
  end.sum
end

batting #=> 33
batting #=> 0
batting #=> 18
```

Using `loop` this continually creates random numbers from 0 - 6 with `rand 7`. We use a ternary operator to stop the loop with `StopIteration` if x == 0, otherwise we push `x` into the `obj` array (which is initially `[]`). Finally we sum the `obj` array.

Key methods: `loop`, `Enumerable#with_object`, `rand`, `Array#sum`

Comment: huh, `raise(StopIteration)`? Why not a simple `break`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev well I'm in two minds. Especially after reading this discussion in the comments here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41173887/5101493

Comment: @MrityunjeyanS `break` would require you to pass `obj` as an argument. Otherwise I'm not so sure, See link above for a discussion about this.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Okay! But in your code, are you listing all the random numbers generated in an array and having the sum of the array list? Instead, I wanted to have the sum in the variable, so that each time, I have it zero, the sum can be populated to the variable and that can be added to the final score? Your code, works fine, when I generate it just once? In case, I do generate it next time, the previous data is lost. Is it like now I ll have to create like `variable = loop.with_object([]) do |_,obj|` ?

Comment: @sagarpandya82: btw, `break` does _not_ require an object.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev if you use `break` and don't pass it the argument `obj` then it overrides `with_loop`'s return value, and returns `nil` every time.